# Find id of last inserted row

Tags: android

I have to simple tables in SQLite in my app and I need to insert into my tables values, but when I insert into the first I need to find value id ( primary key first column ) and that to be foreign key in second table. I know to find this with select last but is there better way to find this, id of last inserted row ?

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase then you can use insert() which returns the id of the inserted row: [see here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29)

Answer (score 3):

use

```
SELECT last_insert_rowid()
```